# How to prevent same object from being picked from array twice in a row

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, random, object-pooling

I am having a bit of a problem figuring out how to randomly get an object out of a list that wasn't picked on the last update of a script. When this randomly instantiated object is spawned and reaches a certain y value, it will set itself to inactive. So when this object is not active, it will go through an array and pick another object at random. However, I do not want to include the previous active object.

example: blue ball was first active. Moves on the Y axis. Becomes inactive. Next object spawn should have no chance of being a blue ball. Any ideas and help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is below

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ballGeneratorShooter : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int ballSelector;
    private TagNumber theTagNumber;
    public ObjectPooler[] theObjectballPools;//In my inspector, I have 5 prefab gameObjects attached
    List<ObjectPooler> changingBalls;

    public bool changeBalls;

    public GameObject currentBall;
    public GameObject newBall;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        changingBalls = new List<ObjectPooler>();
        currentBall = newBall;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (newBall == null)
        {

            ballSelector = Random.Range(0, theObjectballPools.Length);

            newBall = theObjectballPools[ballSelector].GetPooledObject();

            newBall.transform.position = transform.position;
            newBall.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            newBall.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (newBall.activeInHierarchy == false)
        {
            if (changeBalls)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < theObjectballPools.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (theObjectballPools[i].GetPooledObject().GetComponent<TagNumber>().tag != currentBall.GetComponent<TagNumber>().tag)
                    {
                        changingBalls.Add(theObjectballPools[i]);
                    }
                    //changingballs.Add(theObjectballPools[i]);
                }

                ballSelector = Random.Range(0, changingBalls.Count);
                newBall = theObjectballPools[ballSelector].GetPooledObject();
                Debug.Log(changingBalls.Count);
                newBall.transform.position = transform.position;
                newBall.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
                newBall.SetActive(true);
                currentBall = newBall;
                changeBalls = false;
                changingBalls.Clear();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the random number to variable (`lastRandomNum`) each time you generate a random number. Now, use the function below that can generate a random number with `exclusion`.

```
int RandomWithExclusion(int min, int max, int exclusion)
{
    var result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max - 1);
    return (result < exclusion) ? result : result + 1;
}
```

You pass in `0` to `min`, then `theObjectballPools.Length` or `changingBalls.Count` to the `max`, then finally, `lastRandomNum` value to the exclusion parameter.

You also need a `boolean` variable to determine if this is the first run. If this is the first run, use the Unity's `Random.Range` function then set the `firstRun` to `false`. If it is not the `firstRun`, use the `RandomWithExclusion` function from this answer and pass in the `lastRandomNum` value to exclude it. Also, store the generated random number to the `lastRandomNum` variable to be used next frame.

Below is a simplified version of what I said above. You have to incorporate that to your code.

```
GameObject[] yourItem = null;
bool firstRun = true;
int lastRandomNum = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (firstRun)
    {
        firstRun = false;
        //First run, use Random.Range
        lastRandomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, yourItem.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        //Not First run, use RandomWithExclusion
        lastRandomNum = RandomWithExclusion(0, yourItem.Length, lastRandomNum);
    }

    //Do something with the lastRandomNum value below

    newBall = theObjectballPools[lastRandomNum].GetPooledObject();
}

int RandomWithExclusion(int min, int max, int exclusion)
{
    var result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max - 1);
    return (result < exclusion) ? result : result + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try linq :

```
    public class Ball
    {
        public static List<Ball> balls = new List<Ball>();
        public int value { get; set; }
        public Boolean active { get; set; }

        public Ball() {}
        public Ball(int size)
        {
            // initial class
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                balls.Add(new Ball(){ value = rand.Next(), active = false}); 
            }
        }

        public Ball GetRandom()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Ball randomBall = balls.Where(x => x.active == false).Select((x) => new { value = x, randX = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.randX).FirstOrDefault().value;
            randomBall.active = true;
            return randomBall;
        }
    }
```